# Figure Float and Margin

Tags: xml, image, xslt, xsl-fo, docbook

I'm working with DockBook 4.5 and [RenderX's XEP](http://www.renderx.com/) on Ubuntu 13.04. The DocBook translation are provided by Ubuntu.

I'm floating an image to the right (it works using XEP, but no FOP), and I need to add a margin to the image. It appears DocBook does not use a margin, so the text is jammed into the image.

DocBook has a page on [Figure floats](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/FigureFloats.html). Unfortunately, it makes no sense to me and the HTML examples don't apply.

DocBook also has a [FO Parameter Reference](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/1.75.1/doc/fo/) page, but it does not list a property that includes all of figures, floats, and margins.

I tried adding the following overrides to my custom `book-style.xsl` (it was previously 0):

```
<xsl:attribute name="margin-left">6pt</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="margin-right">6pt</xsl:attribute>
```

But it resulted in a number of errors:

```
Document book.xml does not validate
compilation error: file book-style.xsl line 16 element attribute
element attribute only allowed within a template, variable or param
compilation error: file book-style.xsl line 17 element attribute
element attribute only allowed within a template, variable or param
...
```

How does one specify a float margin for a figure or image?

Comment: It's really unclear what you did. Where ever you added those attributes was an incorrect place, hence the error you are getting trying to throw and attribute at that location. you should put padding on whatever you are inserting into the float area to accomplish what you want. As in ... you are not really inserting an image as the child, your are inserting a block that contains an image, pad that.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. "It's really unclear what you did" - its unclear to me too. I'm befuddled at how difficult this stuff is ;) For example, I can't do a `<figure `"margin-left=6"`>. Instead, I have to figure out what to tune in some file because the language does not allow me to simply modify an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As touched upon in a comment by the OP, just using the following is enough to introduce a margin on figures that float right or left:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="figure.properties">
 <xsl:attribute name="margin-left">6pt</xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:attribute name="margin-right">6pt</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

I think my original answer (below) was unnecessarily complicated.

---

The template named `floater` (see http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/SideFloats.html#CustomSideFloat) outputs the `fo:float` formatting object. This template takes `start.indent` and `end.indent` parameters with default values of 0. These default values are unfortunately not changed when the `figure` template calls `floater`, resulting in the problem that you see.

You only need a small fix in the template matching `figure` to make it work (see the comment in the code below). So add the following to your customization layer:

```
<xsl:template match="figure">
  <xsl:variable name="param.placement"
              select="substring-after(normalize-space($formal.title.placement),
                                      concat(local-name(.), ' '))"/>

  <xsl:variable name="placement">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($param.placement, ' ')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($param.placement, ' ')"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$param.placement = ''">before</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$param.placement"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="figure">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@pgwide = '1'">
        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="pgwide.properties">
          <xsl:call-template name="formal.object">
            <xsl:with-param name="placement" select="$placement"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </fo:block>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="formal.object">
          <xsl:with-param name="placement" select="$placement"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="floatstyle">
    <xsl:call-template name="floatstyle"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$floatstyle != ''">
      <xsl:call-template name="floater">
        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$floatstyle"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="content" select="$figure"/>

        <!-- The following two lines added to introduce a 10pt 'margin' for floats (right or left) -->
        <xsl:with-param name="start.indent">10pt</xsl:with-param> 
        <xsl:with-param name="end.indent">10pt</xsl:with-param>

      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$figure"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks mzjn. I did not use the sample above though it looks like its more correct than my solution. I used `<xsl:attribute-set name="figure.properties">` to change it everywhere. Is till like `<figure "margin-left=6"`>` best of all. Those committee member must have been on drugs when they designed DocBook.

Comment: 'As an alternative, ... and try putting the figure" - I did try that. It did not work (I don't recall what precisely was broken - I think it lacked margins, too).